# JSON Builder to access variable inside JSON array

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonbuilder

I want to change the value of 'action' to "1".

Currently my code is as follows.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get("reqApproval"))
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)

builder.content.action = "1"
vars.put("reqApproval", builder.toPrettyString())
```

The JSON array is like so (excess variables removed)

```
 {
    "requisitionApprovals": [
        {
            "action": ""
        }
     ]
 }
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is to access the action field inside the requisitionApprovals array.

My current solution just adds a variable 'action' outside the array, but I need to access the variable inside the array.

I've tried all the below and they don't work

```
builder.content.requisitionApprovals.action = "1"
builder.content.requisitionApprovals.[0].action = "1"
builder.content.requisitionApprovals[0].action = "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space before and after the array index like so

```
builder.content.requisitionApprovals.[ 0 ].action = "1"
```